# How to format and round down in QWEB report?

Tags: odoo, qweb, odoo-14

In Odoo, I set decimal precision to be 4 for a field. Let's call it `price`.

The field `price` now has a value with 4 decimal places in the database.

It is displayed in a QWEB report, as expected, with 4 decimal places.

However, I need to display it only the first 2 decimal places with round down method.

Desired examples of `price` before and after the rounding.

- 13.4567 ==> 13.45
- 5.0010 ==> 5.00
- 97.8391 ==> 97.83

How to achieve such requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
<span t-esc="'%.2f'%(o.price)"/></span>
```

or:

```
<span t-esc="o.price" t-options='{"widget": "float", "precision": 2}'/>
```

For gane a better control of round precision(up o down) you could write a function to call from qweb that takes `o.price` and retrieve a desired value.

I hope this can be helpful for you.